# Should I use multiple conditions for an if clause when I know one condition depends on the other?

Tags: php, if-statement

I know this question touches the limits of uselessness, but please consider the fact that it's a real doubt that I faced in other similar cases, and that I did research on the topic before asking.

**Scenario**:

I am developing a WordPress plugin in PHP, and I am using nonces to avoid CSFR attacks.

Until now, I just used to check if the form is submitted before taking action on the potential submitted data.

But now, I also want to verify the used nonce token.

For that purpose, WordPress offers the `wp_verify_nonce($nonce)` function.

In many examples I see that the verification is done as follows:

```
if(isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], ... )){
...
}
```

But I have a question, since the second condition clearly depends on the first one.

**Question**:

Would it be more correct to put one condition inside the other, as follows?

```
if(isset( $_POST['nonce'] )){
  if(wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], ... )){
  ...
  }
}
```

The word "correct" can be very relative, but the thing is, why would I run `wp_verify_nonce()` if I don't know the value required by the function is defined at all?

For the generics of this same situation, what is considered to be a better practice?

Comment: Just have a look at early escapes and restructure your code

Comment: _“why would I run wp_verify_nonce() if […]”_ - you _wouldn’t_, with either version - PHP stops evaluating an expression of the form `A && B`, as soon as it determines that `A` is false. `B` will not even be evaluated any more in that case (meaning here, the function call will not happen.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, that's actually The Answer to this question.

Comment: Okay, if that helped already, let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the thing is, why would I run wp_verify_nonce() if I don't know the value required by the function is defined at all?

You *wouldn’t*, with either version - PHP stops evaluating an expression of the form `A && B`, as soon as it determines that `A` is false. `B` will not even be evaluated any more in that case (meaning here, the function call will not happen.)